# Pasting text in zsh in vi mode

Tags: zsh, clipboard, oh-my-zsh, vi-mode

I changed input mode in zsh to `vi` with `set -o vi`, but that created problems with pasting text.

While trying to do `cmd-v` (MacOS) in the insert mode, zsh is pasting only a fraction of the clipboard content. It seems like zsh is trying to execute the clipboard content as if its characters were commands. (Perhaps `cmd-v` sends zsh into the visual mode or something.)

Meanwhile, clipboard paste works fine in `vim` and `bash`. It works in iTerm and Terminal. But not with `zsh`. I use `oh-my-zsh` with `vi-mode` plugin disabled (it has the same problem).

Is this a bug or normal behavior?

Comment: What version of zsh? Recent versions have a new bracketed paste mode; revert to the old behaviour via `unset zle_bracketed_paste`

Comment: @thrig zsh 5.2. I tried adding `unset zle_bracketed_paste` to `~/.zshrc`, but it still behaves like this.

Comment: Can you try without all of the “oh-my-zsh” stuff? I run ZSH in Vi mode on my Mac without it and have no problems. Would be useful to narrow it down to ZSH or “oh-my-zsh”

Comment: @forquare Thanks for suggestion. Checked. It's `oh-my-zsh`-only problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @forquare's reminder, I checked `oh-my-zsh` config and discovered the problem: plugin `safe-paste`.

After removing `safe-paste` from `~/.zshrc`, pasting works in the vi mode.